# Android surfaceChanged incorrect values for width/height

Tags: android, rotation

I've a bitmap that is drawn on a surface and needs to be resized every time the device is rotated. Because of soft buttons, I use this code to get current dimensions (it seems to work ok):

```
public void getCanvasXY(){
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2){
         // HoneyComb 3.2 and up
         DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
         ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
         Global.CanvasX = metrics.widthPixels;
         Global.CanvasY = metrics.heightPixels;
    } else{
         // before HoneyComb
         Global.CanvasX = getWidth();
         Global.CanvasY = getHeight();
    }
}
```

I thought the best place to recalculate the dimensions and create my bitmap was in surfaceChanged().

```
@Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder1, int format, int width, int height) {
                getCanvasXY();
                LoadBMP();
    }
```

I see that this is called more than once, and I get diferent values for CanvasX and CanvasY while device is rotating. The last time it's called works ok, but I see how onDraw() is drawing my bitmap and sprites bad resized and finally ok. It's an ugly effect.
How to solve this? 
thanks

Comment: please spell "heigth" to "height" so this question indexes properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here I assume you mean SurfaceView, where you are using a background thread to draw to a surface and your are using SurfaceHolder.CallBack(). This is not a complete answer, however, this problem also has plagued me for a while. In my late night troubleshooting I managed to put together a workaround which may be a little more elegant than yours. The result being that nothing is drawn until the surfacechanged has settled to it's last state, so the user is unaware of what is happening.

In your surfacechanged you'll notice that your height or width isn't changing to the correct value, in otherwords the result surface if drawn to is MalFormed. What you need is a reference value to what your height and width should be, you can get that by placing the following code before you SetContentView() in your main activity:

```
WindowManager w = getWindowManager();
   Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
   int Meausredwidth = d.getWidth();
   int Measuredheight = d.getHeight();
```

Now from your measured height and width, work out how much you are assigning to the surfaceView, and pass those values to your SurfaceView as global variables. And make sure you are calling the above code in onconfigurationchanged() in your main activity so those values get recalculated each time. Now on your SurfaceView which should somehow implement SurfaceHolder.Callback, Change your surfacechanged to look like this:

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder mholder, int format, int width,
        int height) {

    if (width != mWidth) {
        MalFormed = true;
        thread.setRunning(false);
        count++;

    } else if (width == mWidth) {

        if (MalFormed) {
            MalFormed = false;

            Log.d("ROTATE", "ReDraw");

            thread = new DrawingThread(this, holder, mHandler);
            thread.setRunning(true);
            thread.start();

        }

    }

}
```

Where mWidth is the desired width. Here you may need to change the if statement depending on your specific problem. And MalFormed is a global boolean in your surfaceview.

Now it's important to remember, if a change occurs SurfaceChanged() gets called before SurfaceCreated, which means we can  easily modify any code which attempts to interact with the thread to suit our above changes.

So anywhere where else you are attempting to join or start that background drawing thread you must check first if the surface is MalFormed. E.g.

```
if (thread.getState() == State.TERMINATED){

            if(!MalFormed){
               holder.removeCallback(this);
               holder = getHolder();
               holder.addCallback(this);


               thread = new DrawingThread(this, holder,mHandler);
               thread.setRunning(true);

               thread.start();
            }



        }else{
            if(!MalFormed){
                thread.setRunning(true);

                try {
                    thread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }
```

Hope I'm in the ballpark somewhere. All the best.

Comment: Thanks @digiphd. Check the dimensions at the beginning was what I tried to do, but my Tablet of 800x480 pixels, has soft buttons, and when I obtain the dimensions from the activity, it returns 800x480. But the problem is that really useful are 760x480. Values that I obtain using DisplayMetrics.
The temporary solution: wait a sec, until the rotation is completed, to determine the correct dimensions. Enough to make sure the values ​​do not fluctuate too much. For my app is enough, although I know it's not the most elegant solution.

Comment: Yeah that is similar to my workaround. I just wait until the dimensions match up. Hope this thread helps some other people as well :)